# JavaFX, перерисовка

Tags: java, gui, javafx

У меня есть окно с полем ввода текста для поиска и `VBox` куда выводятся результаты поиска.
Я сделал так что при каждом изменении в текстовом поле из `VBox` все удаляется и заново заполняется, но при этом видно мгновение удаления и заполнения.

```
private void showSearchusers(Object[][] objects) {
    Platform.runLater(()->model.getUsers().clear());
    for (Object[] object : objects) {
        Contact contact = new Contact(object,true,this);
        model.addUsers(contact);

    }
}
```

Собственно хотелось бы узнать есть какой нибудь способ избавится от мерцания при перерисовке, мб заморозить анимацию на несколько мс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение своей проблемы при помощи `AnimationTimer`.

```
private void showSearchusers(Object[][] objects) {
    AnimationTimer at = new AnimationTimer() {
//            Здесь кол-во тиков прорисовки
        int fps = 0;
//            Этот метод вызывается каждый раз когда JavaFX обновляет изображение, обычно это 60 раз в сек.
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            fps++;
            if (fps>1){
                Platform.runLater(()->model.getUsers().clear());
                for (Object[] object : objects) {
                    Contact contact = new Contact(object,true,getThis());
                Platform.runLater(()->model.getUsers().add(contact));
                }
//                    Сбрасываем счетчик и останавливаем анимацию
                fps=0;
                this.stop();
            }

        }
    };
//        Запускаем анимацию
at.start();
}
```

Хоть в примере я и выставил обновление через 1 fps, лично у меня мерцания прекратились.